# Vue routing not rendering correct

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I don't get redirected to login page when the role is "user".I have two getters in my route. One getter to check if the user is authenticated and another getter to get userRole. The userRole contains this: [“user”]. When i console log the getter i get the correct values but when i console.log a string, I don't see it as an orange string value in my console.

```
    name: "GrantQuotes",
    component: GrantQuotes,
    beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
      const authStatus = store.getters["auth/userRole"];
      const myArrStr = JSON.stringify(authStatus);
      const obj = JSON.parse(myArrStr);
      console.log(obj);
      console.log("user");

      if (!store.getters["auth/authenticated"] && obj.includes("user")) {
        return next({
          name: "Login",
        });
      }

      next();
    },
  },
```

Also my `obj.includes("user")`returns true.

```
export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    accessToken: null,
    user: null,
    roles: null,
  },

  getters: {
    authenticated(state) {
      return state.accessToken && state.user;
    },

    user(state) {
      return state.user;
    },
    userRole(state) {
      console.log("test");
      return state.roles;
    },
  },

  mutations: {
    SET_TOKEN(state, accessToken) {
      state.accessToken = accessToken;
    },

    SET_USER(state, data) {
      state.user = data;
    },
    SET_ROLE(state, data) {
      state.roles = data;
      console.log(data, "hej");
    },
  },

  actions: {
    async register({ dispatch }, credentials) {
      let response = await axios.post(
        "http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signup",
        credentials
      );
      return dispatch("attempt", response.data.accessToken);
    },

    async signIn({ dispatch }, credentials) {
      let response = await axios.post(
        "http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin",
        credentials
      );
      return dispatch("attempt", response.data.accessToken);
    },

    async attempt({ commit, state }, accessToken) {
      if (accessToken) {
        commit("SET_TOKEN", accessToken);
      }

      if (!state.accessToken) {
        return;
      }

      try {
        let response = await axios.get(
          "http://localhost:3000/api/auth/userMe",
          {
            headers: {
              "x-access-token": accessToken,
            },
          }
        );
        console.log(response.data);
        commit(
          "SET_ROLE",
          response.data.roles.map((role) => role.name)
        );
        commit("SET_USER", response.data);
      } catch (e) {
        commit("SET_TOKEN", null);
        commit("SET_USER", null);
      }
    },

    signOut({ commit }) {
      commit("SET_TOKEN", null);
      commit("SET_USER", null);
    },
  },
};
```

This is my user object

```
1. {roles: Array(1), quotes: Array(5), _id: "6089da8bd846c7e42a196ac5", username: "jon", email: "jon@gmail.com", …}

  1. email: "jon@gmail.com"
  2. quotes: (5) ["6089e8346dba89414317e646", "6089e8d96dba89414317e647", "608abd11462bf51a1583ab05", "60c5e89d1a6cfb0f3b16f51f", "60c62dc21a6cfb0f3b16f520"]
  3. roles: Array(1)

    1. 0: {_id: "607a0a5d102d2f5ad7738adf", name: "user", __v: 0}
    2. length: 1
    3. __proto__: Array(0)

  4. username: "jon"
  5. __v: 10
  6. _id: "6089da8bd846c7e42a196ac5"
  7. __proto__: Object
```

Comment: I'm also a bit confused on this. What exactly is the problem you're experiencing? If this is a problem with what you're wanting to see in the debug console, this is neither a Vue problem or a router/rendering problem.

Comment: I changed my question to be a bit more clear. My route is not rendering to the login page when the getter contains the role "user".  Forget the thing I wrote about the orange string value. I was just really tired after a lot of debugging  and not finding anything. I stringified and parsed it because i got an proxy of the object. @tony19

Comment: @Joseph. I updated the question. The routing should go to login page when userRole is "user"

Comment: Your code only goes to `Login` when the user role includes `user` *and* `store.getters["auth/authenticated"]` is false. Have you verified the value of `store.getters["auth/authenticated"]` is false? Are you actually getting into the `if` block? Is your router config setup properly with the route name that you're using (`Login`)?

Comment: `console.log(store.getters["auth/authenticated"])` returns user object `Proxy {roles: Array(1), quotes: Array(5), _id: "6089da8bd846c7e42a196ac5", username: "jon", email: "jon@gmail.com", …}`And if I `console.log(!store.getters["auth/authenticated"])` i get the value false. I am getting into the if block but i am not getting to the login but to the `next()`. The code seems to work when i remove the "!".@tony19

Comment: @tony19 . I am not handling the getter when it has the value null. Is this something that causes the problem

Comment: This seems too difficult to troubleshoot without a sample reproduction. Can you share a link to a Codesandbox that reproduces the problem?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-cloud-zbg1u?file=/README.md.   @tony19

Comment: @Jonnie123 You've already kind of answered your own question. You said that `!store.getters["auth/authenticated"]` is returning false. This means that your if statement is evaluated to false, as `if (false && true)` will always be false. your `!store.getters["auth/authenticated"]` will always prevent you from going to login as long as that object is non-null and non-empty. I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish on that line - should the "auth/authenticated" getter return a bool instead of an object?

Comment: If !store.getters["auth/authenticated"] returns an object then it cannot be false. But if the object is empty or null then it can be false. It works now when I added this code `if (
        (!store.getters["auth/authenticated"] && obj === null) ||
        obj.includes("user")
      )`.. I am not really sure why, i have a vague idea @Joseph

Comment: @Jonnie123 The sandbox you linked doesn't contain the code in question.

Comment: @Jonnie123 I believe you're incorrect - if `store.getters["auth.authenticated"]` is returning an object, !store.getters["auth.authenticated"] will evaluate to false. A non-empty object, when converted to a boolean, is true, so `store.getters["auth.authenticated"] == true`. Therefor, `!store.getters["auth.authenticated"] == false`. You can test the same thing in your debug console - `var storeObj = {me: 'something'}; console.log(storeObj); console.log(!storeObj);`. The first value to be logged is `{me: 'something'}`. The second is `false`. The same thing is happening in your code.